# Multiple Struct switch?

Tags: struct, go

Let's say I have an application that receives json data in two different formats.

```
f1 = `{"pointtype":"type1", "data":{"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2"}}`
f2 = `{"pointtype":"type2", "data":{"col3":"val3", "col3":"val3"}}`
```

And I have a struct associated to each type:

```
type F1 struct {
  col1 string
  col2 string
}

type F2 struct {
  col3 string
  col4 string
}
```

Assuming that I use the `encoding/json` library to turn the raw json data into the struct:
    type Point {
      pointtype string
      data json.RawMessage
    }

How can I decode the data into the appropiate struct just by knowing the pointtype?

I was trying something along the lines of :

```
func getType(pointType string) interface{} {
    switch pointType {
    case "f1":
        var p F1
        return &p
    case "f2":
        var p F2
        return &p
    }
    return nil
}
```

Which is not working because the returned value is an interface, not the proper struct type.
How can I make this kind of switch struct selection work?

[here is a non working example](http://play.golang.org/p/mjNeWlAw6j)

Comment: An alternative way would be to use maps (it's supported by the native json package).

Comment: Sebastien Im not sure i understand. Do you have any example i can check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) on the interface returned from your method:

```
switch ps := parsedStruct.(type) {
    case *F1:
        log.Println(ps.Col1)
    case *F2:
        log.Println(ps.Col3)
}
```

..etc. Remember, for the `encoding/json` package to decode properly (via reflection), your fields need to be exported (uppercase first letter).

Working sample: http://play.golang.org/p/8Ujc2CjIj8

Comment: I think this is it!. Would there be a way of returning the right type object instead of having to perform inside each switch case?

Comment: No there isn't.. that wouldn't work. You need to know the type of object .. because they have different fields. The type switch allows your to know which object you're accessing within a given context. If you instead opted for both objects to have the same field names .. then you could have them implement an interface whose methods return the values to you. Other than that, this is the only way.

Comment: Then of course, your other option is to remove the objects completely and just have it deserialize to a `map[string]string` instead. The code won't be as easy on the eyes though..

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to use maps (supported by the native json package).

Here I assume that each data attribute (col1, col2 ...) exists, but maps allows you to check it.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type myData struct {
    Pointtype string
    Data map[string]string
}

func (d *myData) PrintData() {
    if d.Pointtype == "type1" {
        fmt.Printf("type1 with: col1 = %v, col2 = %v\n", d.Data["col1"], d.Data["col2"])
    } else if d.Pointtype == "type2" {
        fmt.Printf("type2 with: col3 = %v, col4 = %v\n", d.Data["col3"], d.Data["col4"])
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Unknown type: %v\n", d.Pointtype)
    }
}

func main() {
    f1 := `{"pointtype":"type1", "data":{"col1":"val1", "col2":"val2"}}`
    f2 := `{"pointtype":"type2", "data":{"col3":"val3", "col4":"val4"}}`

    var d1 myData
    var d2 myData

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(f1), &d1)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(f2), &d2)

    d1.PrintData()
    d2.PrintData()
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/5haKpG7MXg